# PHP PDO BindValue not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to create a basic rating function using PHP, SQL, PDO, which adds the value of the rating that a user gives to the field "recipe_rating" and then adds 1 to the field "recipe_ratingcounter".

However, something is not quite right with my code below! The two lines `$query1->bindValue(2, $recipename);` and `$query2->bindValue(1, $recipename);` are not working properly, as they are not actually binding anything to the corresponding question marks in the SQL statement. I believe that the SQL is correct as when I replace these `$recipename` variables in the lines above with a string such as 'Tuna Pasta', the whole function works perfectly. I have also used var_dump on this variable to ensure that it does actually contain a string.

```
if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
$name = $_GET['name'];
$recipedetails = $recipe->get_recipe($name);

    if (isset($_POST["Submit"])) {
    $selectedrating = $_POST["rating"];
    $recipename = $recipedetails['recipe_name'];
    $recipename = "'".$recipename."'";

    global $con;
    $query1 = $con->prepare("UPDATE emptyfridge SET recipe_rating = recipe_rating + ? WHERE recipe_name = ?");
    $query1->bindValue(1, $selectedrating);
    **$query1->bindValue(2, $recipename);**
    $query1->execute();
    $query2 = $con->prepare("UPDATE emptyfridge SET recipe_ratingcounter = recipe_ratingcounter + 1 WHERE recipe_name = ?");
    **$query2->bindValue(1, $recipename);**
    $query2->execute();
}
```

Comment: Are your recipe names supposed to contain quotes ('')? $recipename will end up being "'name'", instead of "name".

Answer (score 0):

Use bindValue to replace placeholder variables prepended with a colon :

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Specifically:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindValue(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

In your case:

```
$query1 = $con->prepare("UPDATE emptyfridge SET recipe_rating = recipe_rating + :recipe_rating WHERE recipe_name = :recipe_name");
    $query1->bindValue( ':recipe_rating', $selectedrating );
    $query1->bindValue( ':recipe_name', $recipename );
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

You may be adding extra quotes to your strings unnecessarily with this line:

```
$recipename = "'".$recipename."'";
```

It looks like you are trying to potentially escape $recipename, but since you are using PDOs, you should remove this, as they will handle this for you.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion as well but unfortunately this does not work either